# Настройка сети в Centos7

Tags: linux, сеть, centos

С переходом от VirtualBox к VMware не получается настроить сеть в Centos7(Статический IP)

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33:

TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.1.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="ens33"
DEVICE="ens33"
ONBOOT="yes"

/etc/sysconfig/network:

NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos7
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1

/etc/resolv.conf:

nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

[image]

Comment: Добавите вывод `ip address` В вопрос, и лучше текстом (скопируйте из терминала, а не делайте скриншот). Проверте правильность настройки сети  VMware

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать утилиту nmtui

Установить утилиту:

```
yum install NetworkManager-tui
```

Cписок сетевых адаптеров можно получить командой:

```
nmcli device status
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверь настройки ipv6 на VMware. Возможно не не убрали эту опцию на ESXI. И выложи сюда вывод `ip a`. Так же можно посмотреть где обрывается запрос `traceroute 192.168.1.1`. Этот хост вообще живой?